# How to program Gauss-Seidel Method from Jacobian since when it hits the j-loop it throws an error when doesn't recognize the element location 0?

Tags: matlab, gaussian

So here is the code that I wrote for the Gauss-Seidel Method that is actually derived from the Jacobi code. The problem is that once it hits the j-loop, that is the error. Since MATLAB does not recognize element location 0 in an array, this is technically an error. How can I compensate for this?

This represents the Ax = b matrix function.

```
function result = GaussSeidel(A,b,x)
kmax = 100; sigma = 0.5e-4;
n = size(A);

for k=1:kmax
    y = x;
    for i=1:n
        sum = b(i);
        diag = A(i,i);
        for j=1:(i-1)
            sum = sum - (A(i,j)*x(j));
        end
        for j=(i+1):n
            sum = sum - (A(i,j)*x(j));
        end
        x(i) = sum/diag;
    end
    result = x(k);
    if norm(x-y) < sigma
        result = x(k);
        return
    end
    return
end
```